Can a "proper" Linux userspace run on an Android kernel?
I've been reading about the challenges of getting Android phones to boot up using a close to mainline Linux kernel, and it got me thinking, manufacturers have their own kernels with all the correct drivers, and Android ROMs like LineageOS use these kernels with great success on many devices (of course it's not 100% there due to SafetyNet, etc. but the majority of features work).
So my question is: is it possible to use these kernels to boot a conventional Linux userspace by having them start up something like systemd instead of Android's init? If not, what prevents that?

Have you read the Google documentation about Android kernel? Your question seems to like you make the Android kernel larger/more important than it is. Regarding the drivers there is often no choice, include it to be able to use a certain device or leave it out and have a hardware device that can't be or only partially used.

See the related part here: How to boot Ubuntu on Android device? and Is it possible to create an operating system other than Android for Android devices?
